# How to use MediatR AbstractValidator to compare 2 or more variables

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, fluentvalidation, mediatr

Is it possible to write rule for command that will compare two or more variables?

I got DeleteUserCommand (userId, userIdToRemove) and I want to set a rule that this two variables are not equal.

```
public class DeleteUserCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<DeleteUserCommand>
{
    public DeleteUserCommandValidator()
    {
        //rule: if command.UserId == command.UserIdToRemove then throw ValidationException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Must method of validator like this:

```
public class DeleteUserCommand
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid IdToDelete { get; set; }
}



//validator
public class DeleteUserCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<DeleteUserCommand>

{
    public DeleteUserCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(v => v.Id).Must((command, id) =>
        {
            return command.Id == command.IdToDelete;
        });

    }

}
```

more information on this [link](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html).